# Keras модель не видит один из входов

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

архитектура сверточного CVAE:

```
    hiden_dim = 2
    num_classes = 10
    #ENCODER__________
    data_input = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
    encoder_label_input = Input(shape=(num_classes,))
    
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(data_input)
    x = dropout_bn(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    x = dropout_bn(x)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    shape_before_hiden_dim = K.int_shape(x)[1:-1] + (1,)
    x = dropout_bn(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    
    x = concatenate([x, encoder_label_input])
    z_mean = Dense(hiden_dim)(x)
    z_log_variance = Dense(hiden_dim)(x)
    h = Lambda(sample_point, output_shape=hiden_dim)([z_mean, z_log_variance])
    
    #DECODER__________
    hiden_input = Input(shape=hiden_dim)
    decoder_label_input = Input(shape=num_classes)
    
    d = concatenate([hiden_input, decoder_label_input])
    
    print(shape_before_hiden_dim)
    d = Dense(np.prod(shape_before_hiden_dim), activation='relu')(d)
    d = Reshape(shape_before_hiden_dim)(d)
    d = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(d)
    d = dropout_bn(d)
    d = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(d)
    d = dropout_bn(d)
    d = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(d)
    # d = Activation('sigmoid')
    
    encoder = Model([data_input, encoder_label_input], h, name='encoder')
    encoded = encoder([data_input, encoder_label_input])
    
    decoder = Model([hiden_input, decoder_label_input], d, name='decoder')
    decoded = decoder([encoded, decoder_label_input])
    
    model = Model([data_input, encoder_label_input, decoder_label_input], decoded, name='CVAE')
    model.compile(loss=combined_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=[calculate_reconstruction_loss, calculate_kl_loss])
```

пытаюсь обучить:

```
model.fit(x=[x_train, y_train, y_train], y=x_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=60000)
```

получаю:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_3' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
     [[{{node input_3}}]]
     [[batch_normalization/cond_1/switch_pred/_23/_232]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_3' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
     [[{{node input_3}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

как я понимаю проблема в том что данные с input_3 (является выходом енкодера) не попадают в декодер почему-то. plot_model(model, show_shapes=True) дает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вроде бы проблема не в некорректном подключении инпутов. Может я неправильно подаю данные в model.fit? Пробовал в разных последовательностях и все равно не выходит.

UPD:
Такая упрощенная модель, но с той же последовательностью объединений инпутов запускается на тренировку:

```
enc_input = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
enc_label_input = Input(shape=(10))
#ENCODER
x = Flatten()(enc_input)
x = concatenate([x, enc_label_input])
x = Dense(2)(x)
#DECODER
dec_input = Input(shape=(2))
dec_label_input = Input(shape=(10))
d = concatenate([dec_input, dec_label_input])
d = Dense(784)(d)
d = Reshape((28, 28, 1))(d)

encoder = Model(inputs=[enc_input, enc_label_input], outputs=x, name='encoder')
encoded = encoder([enc_input, enc_label_input])

decoder = Model(inputs=[dec_input, dec_label_input], outputs=d, name='decoder')
decoded = decoder([encoded, dec_label_input])

model = Model(inputs=[enc_input, enc_label_input, dec_label_input], outputs=decoded, name='CVAE')
model.compile(loss='MSE', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=[x_train, y_train, y_train], y=x_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=100)
```

Comment: похоже дело все таки в неверной форме, выходящей из encoder - а. Но не понимаю почему: все числа в упрощенной тестовой модели подставлены такие же как в полноценной